# Infinite union over disjoint sets in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

We have

$$\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} (k, k+1) $$

what would the infinite union look like?
I have tried for some k,

k=-1:  (-1,0)

k=0:   (0,1)

k=1:   (1,2)

so for example would it be for k=-1:1

${\bigcup^{k=1}_{k=-1}{(k, k+1)}} $ = $$(-1,2) \setminus \{0,1\}$$?
so the interscetion of the intervals minus the integer points?

therefor would that be

$$\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} (k, k+1) = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}?$$

Comment: Yes, $\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} (k, k+1) = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Fred. thank you! :)